# $\sum_n \dim(R_n)z^n $

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, invariant-theory, hilbert-polynomial

I solved the following problem using Molien's theorem, but I would like to know another solution.

> Let $R = \oplus R_n$ be the subring of the graded ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ of polynomials invariant under the automorphism that multiplies $x$ and $y$ by $e^{2\pi i/k}$, where $k$ is a positive integer. Calculate the function $\sum_n \dim(R_n)z^n $, where $R_n$ is the subspace of polynomials in $R$ of degree $n$.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my solution:

Using Molien's theorem, we get:

$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(\dim R_n)z^n = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \frac{1}{\det(I_2 - ze^{2\pi i/j}I_2)} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \frac{1}{(1 - ze^{2\pi i/j})^2} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n(ze^{2\pi i/j})^{n - 1} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bigg( \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1} e^{2\pi i (n - 1)/j} \bigg) n z^{n - 1} = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n + 1)\big(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} e^{2 \pi n i/j}\big)z^n$

Also, I would like to know how to transform the last expression since I need integers as coefficients of $z^n$ (they represent the dimension of $R_n$).

Comment: Btw, have you tried to figure out who's $R$? (Eventually can start with some monomials.)

Comment: @ user26857 I've been thinking about it, but I do not know who's $R$.

Comment: If you have difficulty figuring out what $R$ is, I suggest that you try the case $k=2$ first.

Comment: Ok, I give up! Who is $R$?

Comment: I tried to find the polynomials that stay invariant after the action of $e^{2\pi i/k}$